# LAST_VALUE and FIRST_VALUE

Tags: sql, window-functions

I need to make a query that shows stocks (incoming and outgoing) for model in October 2021. The point is that for obtaining incoming and outgoing stocks I need to get vt_stocks_cube_sz.qty respectively for the first day of month and for the last day of month .

Initially, I have a table called vt_stocks_cube_sz which contains daily stocks for each shop (id_stock), model(modc_barc2). I do not need shop data that is why I made a subquery which groups stocks data.

Initial database:

```
 0   N_YEAR               67099 non-null  int64         
 1   N_MONTH_Y            67099 non-null  int64         
 2   id_calendar          67099 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 3   id_stock             67099 non-null  int64         
 4   parent_modc_barc     67099 non-null  object        
 5   qty                  67099 non-null  int64         
 6   price24_25_261       67099 non-null  float64       
 7   price82_wNDS         67099 non-null  float64       
 8   price8_wNDS          67099 non-null  float64       
 9   id_intel             67099 non-null  int64         
 10  vipusk_type          67099 non-null  object        
 11  id_calendar_int      67099 non-null  int64         
 12  id_calendar_int_boh  67099 non-null  int64         
 13  price421             67099 non-null  float64       
 14  modc_barc2           67099 non-null  object        
 15  dd_sales             67099 non-null  int64         
 16  present_full         0 non-null      object        
 17  dd_sales_boh         67099 non-null  int64         
 18  price24_25_261_ALT   67099 non-null  float64       
 19  season_old_new       0 non-null      object        
 20  season_old_new_EOH   0 non-null      object
```

```
N_YEAR  N_MONTH_Y   id_calendar id_stock    parent_modc_barc    qty price24_25_261  price82_wNDS    price8_wNDS id_intel    vipusk_type id_calendar_int id_calendar_int_boh price421    modc_barc2  dd_sales    present_full    dd_sales_boh    price24_25_261_ALT  season_old_new  season_old_new_EOH
0   2021    10  2021-10-01  211 1178146 2   732.0   2688.716545 2725.4545   1   Retail Regular Price    720211001   720211002   784.0   BAC008663 черный    65  None    66  732.0   None    None
1   2021    10  2021-10-01  215 1178146 1   366.0   1344.358273 1362.7273   1   Retail Regular Price    720211001   720211002   392.0   BAC008663 черный    65  None    66  366.0   None    None
2   2021    10  2021-10-01  306 1178146 1   366.0   1344.358273 1362.7273   1   Retail Regular Price    720211001   720211002   392.0   BAC008663 черный    65  None    66  366.0   None    None
3   2021    10  2021-10-01  338 1178146 2   732.0   2688.716545 2725.4545   1   Retail Regular Price    720211001   720211002   784.0   BAC008663 черный    65  None    66  732.0   None    None
4   2021    10  2021-10-01  410 1178146 1   366.0   1344.358273 1362.7273   1   Retail Regular Price    720211001   720211002   392.0   BAC008663 черный    65  None    66  366.0   None    None
```

I am using a window function LAST_VALUE for it.

However, LAST_VALUE function doesn't work correctly. I expected to receive value for the last date (2021-10-31 - 3116) in every row, but received stocks for each date. It seems to me that this function did nothing. Although my data won't being grouped monthly. And when a add group by clause, I see an error that I need to add every column of LAST) VALUE function to group by clause.

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    stocks.id_calendar,
    stocks.modc_barc2,
    stocks.N_MONTH_Y,
    LAST_VALUE(stocks.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY stocks.N_YEAR,
                                              stocks.N_MONTH_Y,
                                              stocks.modc_barc2
                                 ORDER BY stocks.id_calendar) stocks
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.modc_barc2, 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.N_MONTH_Y, 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.id_calendar,
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.N_YEAR,
         SUM(vt_stocks_cube_sz.qty) qty
     FROM 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz
     GROUP BY 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.modc_barc2, 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.N_MONTH_Y, 
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.id_calendar,
         vt_stocks_cube_sz.N_YEAR) stocks
WHERE 
    stocks.N_YEAR = 2021 AND 
    stocks.N_MONTH_Y = 10  AND 
    stocks.modc_barc2 = \'BAC008663 черный\'
```

OUTPUT:

```
    id_calendar modc_barc2  N_MONTH_Y   stocks
0   2021-10-01  BAC008663 черный    10  4672
1   2021-10-02  BAC008663 черный    10  4613
2   2021-10-03  BAC008663 черный    10  4569
3   2021-10-04  BAC008663 черный    10  4561
4   2021-10-05  BAC008663 черный    10  4551
5   2021-10-06  BAC008663 черный    10  4533
6   2021-10-07  BAC008663 черный    10  4524
7   2021-10-08  BAC008663 черный    10  4504
8   2021-10-09  BAC008663 черный    10  4454
9   2021-10-10  BAC008663 черный    10  4415
10  2021-10-11  BAC008663 черный    10  4393
11  2021-10-12  BAC008663 черный    10  4373
12  2021-10-13  BAC008663 черный    10  4349
13  2021-10-14  BAC008663 черный    10  4298
14  2021-10-15  BAC008663 черный    10  4244
15  2021-10-16  BAC008663 черный    10  4147
16  2021-10-17  BAC008663 черный    10  4059
17  2021-10-18  BAC008663 черный    10  3998
18  2021-10-19  BAC008663 черный    10  3960
19  2021-10-20  BAC008663 черный    10  3921
20  2021-10-21  BAC008663 черный    10  3883
21  2021-10-22  BAC008663 черный    10  3785
22  2021-10-23  BAC008663 черный    10  3648
23  2021-10-24  BAC008663 черный    10  3510
24  2021-10-25  BAC008663 черный    10  3437
25  2021-10-26  BAC008663 черный    10  3382
26  2021-10-27  BAC008663 черный    10  3315
27  2021-10-28  BAC008663 черный    10  3264
28  2021-10-29  BAC008663 черный    10  3210
29  2021-10-30  BAC008663 черный    10  3146
30  2021-10-31  BAC008663 черный    10  3116
```

As an example I made a slice only for one model (BAC008663 черный).

Could you help me to split the stocks, I cannot understand how to write the query correctly.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: remove `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: As noted in the [documentatopn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-first_value-and-last_value-in-a-computed-expression) the default scope for a windowed function is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` when an `ORDER BY` is included. Without declaring the range, the above is expected.